# Can you had multiple values to a property in JavaScript Class?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, properties, javascript-objects

The point of this is to attach multiple tags (example: sci-fi, aliens, spaceships) when a user registers a new book, and chooses from an already existing set of tags. There is more to this but for simplification purposes this is all I ask.
For example, can the property tags have multiple values, like be an array, so I can access them after?

Like the tags you put on a question when you ask it here.

```
class Book{
   constructor(title, cover, autor, tags){
      this.title = title;
      this.cover = cover;
      this.autor = autor;
      this.tags = tags;
}
```

Comment: yeah 100% - objects are kind of a big deal :)  javascript is great for playing around because it's so loosely typed.  Each time you instantiated a `new Book()` you could pass in any data type you like.

Comment: check out my answer on how to use your constructor, and access the object created.  hope it helps

Comment: Yes, a property can have an array as a value, if that's what you're asking for.

Comment: Ok that is what I taught I should have tested it myself but I wanted a good explanation. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an object property can be an array. Your code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can have arrays and properties in classes.

Comment: "*and*" makes no sense here

Answer (score 0):

So you've got your constructor:

```
class Book{
  constructor(title, cover, author, tags){
    this.title = title;
    this.cover = cover;
    this.author = author;
    this.tags = tags;
}
```

Now all you need to do is instantiate it, and access it:

```
// presuming you have the params to pass in from somewhere
var someBook = new Book(title, cover, author, tags);

//to access, use either syntax styles:
var someBooksTags = someBook['tags']  // name of prop accessing as string
var someBooksTitle = somebook.title;
```

You will get the `type` back that you put in to the constructor, so if you pass an array of strings/objects as the tags, then that's what you'll get back when you access it.

If you've got any questions, feel free to ask dude.

Edit:  Here's an example with a tags array passed in:

```
var nb_name = 'Awesome Book',
    nb_cover = '../../images/awesomebookcover.png',
    nb_author = {
        name: 'jimbo slim',
        booksPublished: 17
    },
    nb_tags = ['awesome','seasoned author','hardback'];

var book = new Book(nb_name, nb_cover, nb_author, nb_tags);

console.log(book.tags); 
// output: ['awesome','seasoned author','hardback']
```